# Run the same Python code with different dates

Tags: python, loops

I have a python code that I need to re-run for each new set of dates.   Each time I run it I need to change my start and end date in the code.   The code looks like this:

```
startdate = '20150831'
enddate='20160831'
```

Is there a way to automate it so that the code iterates through the dates in my lists and runs the model for each set of dates?

```
startdate =['20150831','20150730','20150630']
enddate = ['20160831','20160730','20160630']
```

Comment: I'm confused. What's the significance for the second (or first) code block?

Comment: Do you need to iterate over `startdates` and `enddates` at the same time? If so, you can iterate over `zip(startdates, enddates)`, where each value will be a tuple with `(startdate, enddate)`.

Comment: Yes, start & end date pair at the same time.  For example, the first run would have for start date '20150831' and end date '20160831'.  The second run would have start date of  '20150730' and end date of '20160730' and so on.  Hope this makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function. It will combine the two lists so that it will look something like this:

```py
>>> list(zip(startdate, enddate)) # Zip returns a zip object, so we need to cast to list to make it readable
# [('20150831', '20160831'), ('20150730', '20160730'), ('20150630', '20160630')]
```

And we can implement it like so

```py
if isinstance(startdate, str): # Making sure that startdate is iterable in the way you want
    startdate = [startdate]
if isinstance(enddate, str):
    enddate = [enddate]

for start, end in zip(startdates, enddates):
    model(start, end) # Run your model through the set
```

Comment: To clarify, would this be written in a separate code or within the same code where the "model" code is.    If it's a separate code, do I use import function to call the code or something else?   How does python know that "model" is the name of my script? IThx.

Comment: Python doesn't know that "model" is the name of the script. I just used `model()` since you were talking about "running the model for each set". And the placement is your choice. As long as it works ;)

Comment: I set up a new script and wrote this code to run another python script called regression_model but it did not work.

Comment: ```start_date =['20150831','20150730','20150630']
end_date = ['20160831','20160730','20160630']

list(zip(start_date, end_date))

if isinstance(start_date, str): # Making sure that startdate is iterable in the way you want
    start_date = [start_date]
if isinstance(end_date, str):
    end_date = [end_date]

for start, end in zip(start_date, end_date):
    regresion_model(start, end) # Run your model through the set
```

Comment: regresion_model is spelled incorrectly @user10425666

Comment: Your solution does not work.  Hope I spelled that correctly.

Comment: @user10425666 No, I mean that the model you're running `regresion_model` is not spelled correctly in the code you pasted in your comment. My solution should work